# 5 equal area polygons

Tags: geometry

Given the quadrilateral ABCD (see drawing) with mid diagonals, E of AC and F of BD, you need to create 5 polygons equal in area to 1/4 of the quadrilateral ABCD area by means of a straight-edge, drawing 9 lines. The 5 polygons - quadrilaterals or triangles - may partially overlap.

[image]

Comment: Are E and F both inside ABCD? Can we use the intersection of AC and BD?

Comment: Yes and yes as the drawing shows. You may use any well defined point that results for intersection of two lines.

Comment: Can the polygon be "pinched off", like two triangles with one vertex in common? Or like ACDB (note the order) in your diagram?

Comment: Yes. What ever polygons you may create by the ruler.

Comment: By "equal in area", do you mean for each polygon individually or for the sum of the 5 polygons to be 1/4 the area of ABCD?

Comment: What is an unsigned ruler? Couldn't you just arbitrarily move 0 on the ruler?

Comment: @Lawrence each polygon has an area of 1/4 of ABCD

Comment: @Ian by unsigned I mean no marked - no ability to measure distance "accurately"

Comment: @Moti, That is normally called a "straight-edge" in geometry, I believe.

Comment: OK. I hope you could deal now with the "real" challenge...:)

Comment: Is the answer specific to this shape, or will any quadrelateral work?

Comment: Hi! Do I understand the challenge correctly? - however we make the cut, we can always take the 4 initial triangles as 4 polygons in the solution. So in essence I only have to find one more polygon with the same area as the other 4 ?

Comment: @Carl The answer is for similar any quadrilateral which has opposite sides not parallel (a hint) and convex.

Comment: @Falco Those are not cuts. The area of any shape of the 5 equals 1/4 of ABCD

Comment: `What ever polygons you may create by the ruler` Can I take this to mean that polygons drawn outside of ABCD are fair game? For example: the triangle formed by B, C, and the eventual intersection of AB, DC. Am I allowed to make my own marks on the straight-edge?

Comment: No limit. This is an acceptable polygon. I am not sure that you could prove that is 1/4 area of ABCD:) But you are thinking out of the box - and this is good.

Comment: Returning to Dr Xorlie's query and your answer, do you accept as one of the polygons two triangles connected like CABEDC? What about differences of triangles, say in ACBD? There are at least 4 of the first and 1 of the second that have an area of 1/4 ABCD.

Comment: Well, if the combination of these two triangles (A 5 sided polygon) area is 1/4 of ABCD, than it is accepted. Differences, only if they create a polygon with the area 1/4 of ABCD

Answer (score 1):

Where it is clear, I will use `XYZ` and `WXYZ` to mean either the shape the area it encloses. Likewise, `XY` will refer to either the line segment or its length.

[image]

Start with the midpoint E of AC.

Since EC = $\frac{1}{2}$AC, we have DEC = $\frac{1}{2}$DAC. (Both triangles have the same perpendicular height from AC to D.) Likewise, BEC = $\frac{1}{2}$BAC.

Summing the areas, we get EBCD = $\frac{1}{2}$ABCD. Call this (1).

Now, DF = FB = $\frac{1}{2}$DB, so DFE = BFE = $\frac{1}{2}$DBE. (All these triangles have the same perpendicular height from DB to E.) Likewise, DFC = BFC = $\frac{1}{2}$DBC. Adding one of each, we get
DEFC = EBCF = $\frac{1}{2}$EBDC. Call this (2).

From (1) and (2), DEFC = EBCF = $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD. With reference to the diagram above, DEFC is composed of the shaded areas P and R, and EBCF is the quadrilateral labelled S. (Note: P, Q and S cross the diagonal lines AC and BD.)

Since DFE = BFE and DFC = BFC, we also have two additional solutions, each composed of two triangles: FEDBCF and FEBDCF. (Although not quadrilaterals, the OP allowed sums and differences of touching triangles as solutions in a comment to the question.)

By a similar construction starting with the midpoint F of DB, we also get ABEF = $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD. ABEF is composed of the shaded areas Q and R. As before, we also get EFACBE and EFCABE as additional solutions.

Now, we have established that P+R = Q+R = S = $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD. So adding the first 3 expressions and decomposing ABCD, we get P+R + Q+R + S = $\frac{3}{4}$(P+Q+R+S+T).

That is, P+Q+R+S+T = 4(T-R), so (T-R) is also $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD.

**This gives a total of 8 shapes produced using 5 lines, with each shape occupying an area $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD.**

Since we are permitted 9 lines, we have 4 additional lines with which to define acceptable polygons. Here are some approaches that might produce acceptable shapes, possibly by completing the triangle formed from the rays AB and DC. In each case, one vertex is not pinned down, but I leave these here for others to play with.

Since (P+R) + S = $\frac{1}{2}$ABCD, the complement T+Q is also $\frac{1}{2}$ABCD. Since ABE < $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD, there is a point G on AD such that DGE = GABE = $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD. Likewise, there is a point H on AD such that FHA = FHDC = $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD.

Since T > $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD, there is a point I on AB that lies between A and the intersection of AB and the ray DE, such that DAI = DIBE = $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD. Likewise, there is a point J on CD such that AJD = AJCF = $\frac{1}{4}$ABCD.

Comment: Yes, on hold. Also, I think you mean EBCF and not EBFC.

Comment: Try to take advantage of the hint in one of the comments

Comment: I would suggest you remove this answer, since it discourage others from attempting, since they think it has been answered.

Comment: @Moti I've revised my answer. Based on your response to my query (in comments under your question), this satisfies the revised parameters for the acceptable shapes.

Comment: the idea is that the points H and G are found. I would claim that there are many points that could provide polygons with an area 1/4ABCD. In any case, I see only three shapes that satisfy the 1/4ABCD. The solution I suggest is  straight clear 5 shapes (polygons)

Comment: @Moti Do FEDBC and its related shapes (5-sided polygons), as well as difference AFED (T-R) not satisfy your requirements? These were the kinds of polygons I asked about in the comments under your question.

Comment: I see now that my response may mislead you. May be I was not clear enough - FEDBC is not a proper solution based on what I am seeking. I will provide a small hint, that may be added to another hint I gave - the other two shapes are triangles which are a 1/4 of ABCD each (which could lead to another feature related to the diagonals mid points)